# Execute simple Logic without "locking" the UI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I have a dialog with some TextBoxes and a button. When this button is clicked I want to change the button's Text, disable the button, start some Logic and then close the Window.

That logic has no return, it just sets a static variable. But it can take a minute because it connects to a DB.

How can I stop the WinForms UI from freezing? I'm looking for a simple approach, if possible no new Classes and Files.

Comment: have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` maybe?

Comment: Background workers are so last season, better techniques exists, but why not.

Comment: Most(all?) DB providers support async programming in a form or another. You should check that out.

Comment: @Andrew I access the DB / Data source via a Class wich gets its data from an interface. A bit complicated, but i don't only get the data from a DB. I would have to make a big refactor of the code without the certainty that every implementation will support async.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
private async void ButtonClick() 
{
    //here, you're on the UI Thread
    button1.Enabled = false;

    await Task.Run(() => DoTheWork());

    //you're back on the UI Thread
    button1.Enabled = true;
}

private void DoTheWork() 
{
    //this will be executed on a different Thread
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative to M.kazemAkhbary's solution :D

Comment: well. i didnt know this way in fact. ill use your way in my own projects ! thanks ! this is actually better. use this way @LukasDörig

Comment: Indeed, it looks very clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a backgroundworker:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = false;

worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
    {
        //perform action
    };

worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        //close window
    };

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: We have TPL/await/async/etc. I would recommend using tasks.

Answer (score 0):

when button is clicked:

```
button.Enabled = false;
button.Text = "new text";
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // do your tasks here and close the window.
    // type your code normally like calling methods. setting variables etc...

    StaticVariable = ExampleUsingMethod();
});
```

if your variable needs to be assigned to UI later then you need dispatcher.for example if you want to change button inside the new thread.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
       Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
       {
          button.Enabled = false;
          button.Text = "new text";
       }

       StaticVariable = ExampleUsingMethod();
});
```

Comment: I would use await/async instead of dispatcher.

Comment: you can manage better in that way but i tried to keep it simple for what OP asked. @Andrew

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thanks for keeping it simple :D

Comment: And I would suggest you prefer `Task.Run` to `Task.Factory.StartNew` to [avoid some traps](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can have a `thread` that performs the calculation.
This may help: [Threads in CSharp](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: This points to article from 2003. In 12 years there's better sources, really.